# Vector fill with CharSequence

Tags: java, android

I have a method that returns a `CharSequence[]` and I need to pass this to a method that requires a `Vector<String>` as input and returns a `Vector<String>`. How do I this? Only with foreach or is there a another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
String[] stringArray = {"a", "b", "c"};
CharSequence[] charSequence = stringArray;
Vector<String> stringVectorA = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
Vector<String> stringVectorB = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList((String[]) charSequence));
```

As `String` implements `CharSequence` you can cast it. Using `Arrays.asList(Collection)` will create you a collection that you can use to create your `Vector` object.
If you face problems casting, check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html. There you can find the correct implementing class for your case.

Comment: Ok. I forgot the magic word "new" like happy new year. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Vector<String> acceptVetcorString(Vector<String> vStr){
    return vStr;
}
public static CharSequence returnCharSequence() {
    return "ABC";
}
```

We have to type cast the arguments to achieve that:

```
acceptVetcorString(new Vector<>(Collections.singletonList((String) returnCharSequence())));
```

Comment: Ok. I forgot the magic word "new" like happy new year. Thank you ;)